# Active MQ tcp connection failure

Tags: tcp, jms, activemq-classic, wso2, wso2-esb

am using Active MQ 5.10 version,I have configured it with wso2esb for message processing.

After around 7-10 days Active MQ is throwing tcp connections failure exception,since ESB is not receiving a successful tcp connection it is failing to submit messages in the Queue.

In this case am restarting the server and again it will run for 7-10 days and the same thing repeats.

my questions is

what may be the exact reason for active MQ stops giving successful tcp connection..?

why after restarting the server it returns to normal state..?

is there any best solution to over come this issue..

memory configuration in activemq.xml file

```
<systemUsage>
   <systemUsage sendFailIfNoSpace="true">
         <memoryUsage>
                <memoryUsage limit="1430 mb"/>
          </memoryUsage>
          <storeUsage>
                <storeUsage limit="300 gb"/>
          </storeUsage>
          <tempUsage>
                <tempUsage limit="100 gb"/>
          </tempUsage>
    </systemUsage>
 </systemUsage>
```

Here is the Proxy service which is placing message in queue. In the proxy service it will check the user authentication if its true the user can place the message in the queue, here i use a class mediator where in that it connects with the active MQ and places message

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="JmsStore2.0"
       transports="https http"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable"
       statistics="enable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence onError="fault">
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
         <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
         <property name="jmsuri" value="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616"/>
         <property name="jmsqueue" expression="get-property('transport', 'jmsqueue')"/>
         <property name="readingspayload" expression="$body" type="OM"/>
         <property name="username" expression="get-property('transport', 'username')"/>
         <property name="password" expression="get-property('transport', 'password')"/>
         <property name="PartyBranchID"
                   expression="//FieldValue/text()"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="Body" expression="$body" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="usercode"
                   expression="fn:substring-before(get-property('username'),'|')"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="clientid"
                   expression="fn:substring-after(get-property('username'),'|')"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="requestMsgId"
                   expression="get-property('MessageID')"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="client_ip_address"
                   expression="get-property('axis2','REMOTE_ADDR')"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>

         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <send xmlns="">
                  <username>$1</username>
                  <password>$2</password>
               </send>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('username')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('password')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send receive="JmsStore_Seq">
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:8282/services/Login2.0" format="soap11">
                  <suspendOnFailure>
                     <errorCodes>101500,101501,101506,101507,101508,101503,50000</errorCodes>
                     <initialDuration>30</initialDuration>
                     <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
                     <maximumDuration>300</maximumDuration>
                  </suspendOnFailure>
               </address>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence onError="fault">
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

Sequence:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
          name="JmsStore_Seq"
          trace="disable">
   <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             name="Authentication"
             expression="//Authentication/text()"/>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             name="UserId"
             expression="//UserId/text()"
             scope="default"
             type="STRING"/>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             name="WorkOUid"
             expression="//WorkOUid/text()"/>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             name="WorkPartyBranchId"
             expression="//WorkPartyBranchId/text()"/>

   <filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
           xpath="get-property('Authentication')=''">
      <then>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <ResponseJSON xmlns="">
                  <Exception>Service trying to connect inactive service</Exception>
                  <Status>101503</Status>
               </ResponseJSON>
            </format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
         <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
         <send/>
      </then>
      <else>
         <filter xpath="get-property('Authentication')='false'">
            <then>
               <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                  <format>
                     <ResponseJSON xmlns="">
                        <Exception>Authentication Failed</Exception>
                        <Status>401</Status>
                     </ResponseJSON>
                  </format>
                  <args/>
               </payloadFactory>
               <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
               <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
               <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
               <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
               <send/>
            </then>
            <else>
               <property name="jmspayload"
                         expression="get-property('readingspayload')"
                         type="OM"/>
               <property name="ResponseJSON" expression="$body/ResponseJSON" type="OM"/>
               <property name="jmsuri" expression="get-property('jmsuri')"/>
               <property name="jmsqueue" expression="get-property('jmsqueue')"/>
               <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                  <format>
                     <PLData>
                        <JMpayload>$1</JMpayload>
                        <AuthData>$2</AuthData>
                        <LogData>
                           <usercode>$3</usercode>
                           <clientid>$4</clientid>
                           <requestMsgId>$5</requestMsgId>
                        </LogData>
                     </PLData>
                  </format>
                  <args>
                     <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('jmspayload')"/>
                     <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('ResponseJSON')"/>
                     <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('usercode')"/>
                     <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('clientid')"/>
                     <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('requestMsgId')"/>
                  </args>
               </payloadFactory>
               <class name="in.youtility.esb.custommediators.JMSStoreMediator"/>
               <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                  <format>
                     <ResponseJSON xmlns="">
                        <Body>
                           <Datalist>
                              <Data>Successfully stored</Data>
                           </Datalist>
                        </Body>
                        <Status>200</Status>
                     </ResponseJSON>
                  </format>
                  <args/>
               </payloadFactory>
               <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
               <header name="To" action="remove"/>
               <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
               <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
               <send/>
            </else>
         </filter>
      </else>
   </filter>
   <description/>
</sequence>
```

Class Mediator:

```
public class JMSStoreMediator extends AbstractMediator implements
```

ManagedLifecycle {

```
Connection connection;

public boolean mediate(MessageContext msgCtx) { 


     try {
         boolean topic=false;
        String jmsuri=""+msgCtx.getProperty("jmsuri");
        String t=""+msgCtx.getProperty("topic");

        if(t.isEmpty()){

            topic=false;
        }
        else {

            topic=Boolean.valueOf(t);
        }

        ConnectionFactory factory= new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(jmsuri);
        connection = factory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination destination=null;
        if(!topic)destination= session.createQueue(""+msgCtx.getProperty("jmsqueue"));
        else destination= session.createTopic(""+msgCtx.getProperty("jmsqueue"));
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);

        String xml = ""+msgCtx.getEnvelope().getBody().toStringWithConsume();

        if(topic){

            JSONObject obj=XML.toJSONObject(xml);
            JSONObject ar=obj.getJSONObject("soapenv:Body");
            ar.remove("xmlns:soapenv");
            xml=ar.toString();
        }
        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(xml);
        producer.send(message);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        log.info("LogLocation = "+getClass().getName()+",Error in storing message in JMS stacktrace is :"+e.toString());
        ((Axis2MessageContext) msgCtx).setProperty(NhttpConstants.HTTP_SC, 500);
        handleException("Error while storing in the message store", msgCtx);

    }
    finally {
        try {
            connection.close();

        } catch (JMSException e) {
            log.info("LogLocation = "+getClass().getName()+",Error in closing JMS connection stacktrace is :"+e.toString());
        }
    }
        log.info("LogLocation = "+getClass().getName()+",ProxyName = "+msgCtx.getProperty("proxy.name")+
            ",Usercode = "+msgCtx.getProperty("usercode")+",Clientid = "+msgCtx.getProperty("clientid")+
            ",requestMsgId = "+msgCtx.getProperty("requestMsgId")+",Position = END"); 

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Is the number of messages growing in ActiveMQ, day after day ? How do you use AMQ, with a JMS proxy service, a MessageStore ?

Comment: hi @Jean-Michel thank you for the reply,Am using ESB proxy service which will drop a message in the queue and other JMS proxy service which will listen to this queue and process it. Frequently messages comes to the queue and get processed with out any issue until Active MQ gives successful tcp connection to ESB.

Comment: I post a first answer, but tell me if the number of messages is growing in ActiveMQ when if begans to fail (thousands of messages waiting in the queues)

Comment: There are no messages waiting in the queue when this problem occurs. all the  messages are processed immediately when it is received.

Answer (score 0):

You should share your proxys conf but you can always verify that :

- You've set the cachelevel to avoid new connections at each scan : `<parameter name="transport.jms.CacheLevel">consumer</parameter>`
- You've asked to consume all messages a each scan : `<parameter name="transport.jms.MaxMessagesPerTask">-1</parameter>`